# how to understand this javascript code consisting kind of numbers

Tags: javascript

This is the javascript code. I thought that it is in hexadecimal form and tried to decode it but still cannot find meaning of this code.
I am using this code in my blogger template. I want to understand the true meaning of this javascript code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/*<![CDATA[*/
var _2507;
var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
var _7971=/[\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46]/;
var _1205=2;
var _1838=_2789.charAt(_2789.length-1);
var _8636;
var _2596=_2789.split(_7971);
var _3552=[String.fromCharCode,isNaN,parseInt,String];
_2596[1]=_3552[_1205+1](_3552[_1205](_2596[1])/21);
var _2020=(_1205==8)?String:eval;_8636='';
_11=_3552[_1205](_2596[0])/_3552[_1205](_2596[1]);
for(_2507=3;_2507<_11;_2507++)_8636+=(_3552[_1205-2]((_3552[_1205](_2596[_2507])+_3552[_1205](_2596[2])+_3552[_1205](_2596[1]))/_3552[_1205](_2596[1])-_3552[_1205](_2596[2])+_3552[_1205](_2596[1])-1));
var _4599='_4241';
var _6610='_4599=_8636';
function _2139(_3635){_2020(_3054);_2139(_7565);_7565(_6610);_2139(_4599);}
var _3054='_2139=_2020';
var _7565='_7565=_2139';_2139(_1838);
/*]]>*/
  </script>
```

Comment: This looks like malware.  The code is intentionally obfuscated so you cannot understand it.  Someone very enterprising would be able to unravel it eventually, but that would take a lot of time.  Do you know what it is supposed to do? Are you running it intentionally, or did you find it (in which case your site is likely  compromised)

Comment: Why are you using this code in your blogger template? What do you expect it to do? Where did you get it?

Comment: could be transpiled from another language into javascript. Remove it and see if anything breaks.

Comment: I remember seeing parts of this code in a question here last week. Lemmie see if I can find the question...

Comment: This is obfuscated code, and the bit about "String:eval" means it will run as javascript whatever it algorithmically pulls out of the big string from the second variable. It's designed not to be able to read, which I would not permit to be used unless I myself obfuscated it from the source code - which I wouldn't do, but still.

Comment: Yup, same essential code, different variable names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895449/deobfuscator-javascript-help-please

Comment: Can you tell use what breaks if you remove it from your blogger template?

Comment: I ran it in my console, and it redirected me to http://www.templateify.com/ Also, it uses jQuery

Comment: What will happen if we try to run this part of code in our script?

Comment: Right now it just includes a stylesheet and inputs some advertising/redirect code. If someone changes the hosted CSS file contents, however, your site will be entirely magically re-skinned to be be about cats. Or naked people. I don't have that much trust in anonymous file hosts - and you shouldn't either :)

Answer (score 4):

Your code has been un-scrambled

```
document.write("
<link href='https://googledrive.com/host/0B-UFNCskEl7Qd25SMUNseFFPQkk' rel='stylesheet' ty
pe='text/css'/>");
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#templateify').html('<a href="http://www.templateify.com">Templateify</a>');
  setInterval(function (){
    if (!$('#templateify:visible').length)window.location.href = 
    'http://www.templateify.com'
  }
  , 1000)
}
)$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#sponsorship').html(
  '<a href="http://www.templateify.com/p/sponsorship.html">Your Link Here</a>');
  setInterval(function (){
    if (!$('#sponsorship:visible').length)window.location.href = 
    'http://www.templateify.com'
  }
  , 1000)
}
)
```

http://wepawet.iseclab.org/view.php?hash=fac68b967bfb84d0d3e84ce0f6589015&type=js

I saved your code into a html file and uploaded it for analysing.

Comment: Oh, and to explain what the code means: the link adds a stylesheet (CSS), and on document ready it puts a sponsorship link to an element with the ID #sponsorship. Its a way to try to 'protect' the stylesheet from being 'stolen' (copied) with no attribution given. How does this obsfuscated mess of attribution make that better? I dunno, someone thought it was a good idea to introduce gaping potential security vulnerabilities just to avoid someone from using a debugger to see where the stylesheet was coming from and what it contained. I declare this practice lame.

Answer (score 3):

The main thing to note here is that `_2020` is `eval`. The code in `function _2139` creates multiple aliases to `eval`:

```
_2020(_3054); => eval("_2139=_2020"); => _2139 = eval;
_2139(_7565); => eval("_7565=_2139"); => _7565 = eval;
_7565(_6610); => eval("_4599=_8636"); => _4599 =_8636;
_2139(_4599); => eval(_8636);
```

So what is `_8636`? If we run the code (and carefully omit the last five lines), we can see that it equals:

```
document.write("<link href='https://googledrive.com/host/0B-UFNCskEl7Qd25SMUNseFFPQkk' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>");
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#templateify').html('<a href="http://www.templateify.com">Templateify</a>');
 setInterval(function () {
     if (!$('#templateify:visible').length) window.location.href = 'http://www.templateify.com'
 }, 1000)
})
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#sponsorship').html('<a href="http://www.templateify.com/p/sponsorship.html">Your Link Here</a>');
 setInterval(function () {
     if (!$('#sponsorship:visible').length) window.location.href = 'http://www.templateify.com'
 }, 1000)
})
```

The code adds an extensive stylesheet from `https://googledrive.com/host/0B-UFNCskEl7Qd25SMUNseFFPQkk`; I assume this is the main benefit sites enjoy from pasting this code into their site. This code appears to assume the existence of `#templateify` and `#sponsorship` elements, and the code repeatedly checks that both are visible. Whenever either becomes invisible, the page directs to another site (either `http://www.templateify.com` or `http://www.templateify.com/p/sponsorship.html`).

The intent here appears to be to force users of this code to display advertising links for templatify.com. Any attempt to hide the links will result in the page being redirected.

It is worth noting that this not a useful way to hide the location of a stylesheet, since any worthwhile Web development tool (such as Chrome's built-in dev tools) will show you the network origins of any stylesheets in use:

[image: Chrome dev tools: Network > Stylesheets]

Comment: Thank You Very much for your response. I have understood this code.Thank you very very much.

Comment: Very well done. I came back to this question to point to as an example [for this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960241/obfuscation-of-script-src) and I'm pleased to see a good analysis on it.