# Obfuscation of script src

Tags: javascript

I need to obfuscate such code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.ru/js?id=159"></script>
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean to obfuscate only this line or the whole Javascript code?

Comment: obfuscate with what purpose?

Comment: You are not going to be able to mask the fact that the browser makes an http request to `site.ru`. That will clearly be visible in the console. (are you trying to distribute malware???)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I know it. I just need to hide this code. Make it unreadable

Comment: By piling on a lot more obfuscated JavaScript to dynamically generate that [like in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936136/how-to-understand-this-javascript-code-consisting-kind-of-numbers#comment29668054_19936136) you can make that bit unreadable, but still, the HTTP request will be plainly visible to anyone who looks. (I have no idea what tool was used to obfuscate the JS in that question)

Comment: The answer depends on why you want to obfuscate this. Are you trying to hide where the script is coming from or trying to hide the script period?

Comment: @Snuffleupagus I trying to hide where the script is coming from

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't. Even if you obfuscate it, once browser downloads it, script URL in unobfuscated form will appear in Web Inspector or Firebug, along with all other loaded resources.

As Web Inspector is standard component of Safari and Chrome and Firebug is one of most popular extensions for Firefox, most users are only a few clicks away from revealing source of your script.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do is most likely a bad idea, but I'll give you an idea to help get you where you want to go.

Use your back end language (I shall assume PHP) to echo the entire contents of the script into the DOM.

```
<?php echo "<script>" . $scriptloadedintovar . "</script>"; ?>
```

This way your script will appear in the page without a src tag.

This is almost kind of reasonable for a small script, but is really doofy for a big one. In general, hiding the locations of your scripts isn't the best security practice. Instead, place your scripts into a folder that is OK to be explored via the web. Most frameworks call this the "webroot" folder, and it is where your images, CSS, and Javascript should live.

Incidentally, if you are trying to hide the fact that your script is coming from another website, that's also a bad idea too. Please don't do that.